# Deep linking to Google Assistant application

Tags: deep-linking, actions-on-google, google-home, deeplink

I have a Facebook Messenger chatbot, which is part of a broader platform, which also includes Google Assistant Action.

In some cases, I want my users to switch from Messenger app to Google Assistant app (both on iOS and Android), so they can speak to my Action.

As far I understood, it's not possible to "push" a message (or "wake up" an Action) to a user through GA Action, so I'd like to forward a user from Messenger to Google Assistant app using some kind of deeplinking. At least - just to launch the app, at best – launch it with forwarded parameters, like "user_id" or a message to be sent to GA on user's behalf.

How do I do it?

How do I know Google Assistant app's deep link "scheme://" for iOS and Android?

Comment: Please show us what you did so far

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the web link that your Action on Google get once it's been published. For example: https://assistant.google.com/services/a/id/66888e9b751b325a/

When the user click on this link (Android or iOS) - It will open the assistant and will start the action.

As for user_id and other authentication methods - At the moment it's not possible.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! It is exactly what I need.
Hope they will add some kind of parameters/payloads to these links soon.

Comment: Actually, I found a problem.

Comment: If a user does not have installed Google Assistant app, this link opens just an Action's page, with no instructions on how to use it or how to install Google Assistant application. I hope that they will improve it in the future.